# Github actions workflow PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory when running bundle exec rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, github-actions

This is my very first question.

I'm trying to integrate `github actions` to my rails project.

I have my ruby.yml like this:

```
name: Ruby

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  test:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Ruby
      uses: ruby/setup-ruby@ec106b438a1ff6ff112340de34ddc62c540232e0
      with:
        ruby-version: 2.6.5
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: bundle install
    - name: Run tests
      run: bundle exec rake
```

The bundle step takes a lot of time, i don't know if i can just load the Gemfile.lock instead of running bundle everytime. But it runs ok.

The problem is the test step.

**So here is the error:**

```
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/home/runner/work/project/project/test/test_helper.rb:10:in `<main>'
/home/runner/work/project/project/test/application_system_test_case.rb:1:in `<main>'
/home/runner/work/project/project/test/system/create_practice_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
/home/runner/work/GPLM/GPLM/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/runner/work/GPLM/GPLM/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:system
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Coverage report generated for Minitest to /home/runner/work/project/project/coverage. 31 / 3352 LOC (0.92%) covered.
SimpleCov failed with exit 1
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Thank you everybody.

Comment: Looks like youre missing a step to setup Postgres. In your build steps you'll also have to setup the postgres admin if you're running the databases server locally.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add Postgres service to your GitHub Action config. For example:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11
      env:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
```

And before `bundle install` you need to install dependent library:

```
- name: Install library for postgres
  run: sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Don't forget about setup database:

```
- name: Setup Database
  run: |
    cp config/YOUR_GITHUB_ACTIONS_DATABASE.yml config/database.yml
    bundle exec rails db:setup
  env:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    RAILS_ENV: test
```

Here, of course, you have to tailor the commands to your individual case.
The easiest way is to have a separate database configuration file specifically for GitHub Actions. But you can also have a special environment for CI.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! But now i have another issue:

Run bundle exec rake
/home/runner/.rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby: invalid option -:  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
For some reason its not recognizing the bundle exec rake command
BTW, thank you so much again

Comment: thank you for your answer. can you pls explain this step: `cp config/YOUR_GITHUB_ACTIONS_DATABASE.yml config/database.yml` ?